# Inverse Query Processing in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I have a RDF Like this

```
@prefix ab: <http://www.example.org/assignment#>.
ab:Sun ab:name "Sun".
ab:Birds ab:name "Birds".
ab:Mountains" ab:name "Mountains".
ab:River ab:name "River".
ab:House ab:name "House".
ab:Land  ab:name "Land".
ab:Boat  ab:name "Boat".
ab:Tree  ab:name "Tree".
ab:Sun ab:right-of ab:Birds;
       ab:above    ab:Mountains.
ab:Birds ab:above ab:Mountains.
ab:Mountains ab:above ab:River;
             ab:above ab:House.
ab:House     ab:above ab:Land;
             ab:right-of ab:Boat.
ab:Land ab:right-of ab:River.
ab:Boat ab:above ab:River.
ab:Tree ab:above ab:House.
```

Its basically a relationship of directions between two objects

My Query is

```
What all are below “Sun” ?
```

I can understand its a form of inverse query processing and I need to interpret “below” as inverse of “above”. But how I do about that, should I use some form of carat operator`^` here

Comment: An inverse path using `^` can be used - as can owl:inverseOf if you use inference. You'll need `+` for the "all" (transitive). Details left to the assignment.

Comment: use the SPARQL 1.1 property paths operator `^` and the asterisk `*`  as suggested